# unable to password_verify a password saved in db with password_hash

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems verifying a password stored in a mySQL database using password_hash.  The insert query takes values from a form

```
query = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, diary) VALUES ('"
        .mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '"
        .password_hash(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']), PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."', '"
        .mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password'])."')";
```

When I try to verify it using

```
if(password_verify(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password'], $row['password']))) {
```

it always comes out as invalid password, even though I know I am entering it correctly.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Do not escape the Password before hashing it

Comment: You escape the string: `$_POST['password'], $row['password']` in `if!`!! but you want `$_POST['password']#`

Comment: Why do you store the password twice? (First one is hashed, second one is plain-text)

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: And your close brackets are a total disaster in the `password_verify()` attempt anyway

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: I store it twice as a test - so I know what the hashed password is based on
That will not be in the final version!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It appears that you have made some mistakes with the parentheses in your `if-statement`.

What you have is this:

```
if (password_verify(
        mysqli_real_escape_string(
            $link, 
            $_POST['password'], 
            $row['password']
         )
     )
) {
```

What happens is that you escape not only `$_POST['password']` but also `$row['password']` because your parentheses are placed incorrectly, while it should be:

```
if (password_verify(
        mysqli_real_escape_string(
            $link, 
            $_POST['password']
        ), 
        $row['password']
    )
) {
```

---

As Jens [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655035/unable-to-password-verify-a-password-saved-in-db-with-password-hash/43655223?noredirect=1#comment74357357_43655035), you should not escape the password before hashing it. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36628423/5914775) has some in-depth information about why you should not escape your passwords before hashing.

And as RiggsFolly [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655035/unable-to-password-verify-a-password-saved-in-db-with-password-hash/43655223?noredirect=1#comment74357463_43655035), your SQL query is still [vulnerable to SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string), even if you escape the input.

Comment: Please read the first comment under the question from @Jens. Escaping the password runs the risk of changing it, Why would you do that?